# Julia convert OffsetArray to one based array

Tags: julia

i use julia image package, most of the operations 
in the package returns an offsetarray with negativ 
or zero based indices, how can i convert such an 
array one based array or amtrix?

thanks

Comment: If you `collect` an OffsetArray the result is a regular array. This might be wasteful, but if the code section is not in a critical loop, it may do they trick. In code: `reg_array = collect(offset_array)`.

Comment: @DanGetz thanks, but unfortunatly it did not the trick, collect returns a matrix with the same negativ indices. also https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/offset-arrays/ dose not help realy!

Comment: Ah, I've tested it on my Julia v0.6.3 and `typeof(collect(offset_array))` is a regular Array. On which version did you test this?

Comment: i ve tested it on julia 0.5

Comment: if you've answered your own question please post it as an answer :)

Comment: You need not accept your own answer. Just post it as an option! (FYI I think your answer seems as good as any I can think that will work on v0.5)

Answer (score 3):

Another method using `parent` function (tested on Julia v0.6.3):

```
julia> using OffsetArrays

julia> a = OffsetArray(rand(3,3), (-2, -2))
OffsetArrays.OffsetArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2}} with indices -1:1×-1:1:
 0.618978  0.515497  0.480304
 0.198965  0.317037  0.546776
 0.484352  0.788388  0.949526

julia> parent(a)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.618978  0.515497  0.480304
 0.198965  0.317037  0.546776
 0.484352  0.788388  0.949526
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly a simple "reshape(A, (dimOneBased))" did it, do not know if it is the right julianish way!